# Spring-Boot actuator /shutdown endpoint forbidden

Tags: spring-boot, curl, spring-boot-actuator

My first-pass with my Spring Boot app had the actuator unsecured, so it was easy to shut down remotely via the /actuator/shutdown endpoint. Recently, I have secured my actuator using Spring security, and it has worked. Now I need to supply http basic credentials to access the endpoints, but now curl calls to the /actuator/shutdown endpoint fail with a Forbidden error. I must have configuration incorrect somewhere.

My curl command:

> curl -XPOST -u actuator:password http://host:port/actuator/shutdown -k

I am able to call other endpoints, it seems only the shutdown endpoint is forbidden.

My config:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.info.git.mode=full
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
management.server.port=8081
spring.security.user.name=actuator
spring.security.user.roles=ACTUATOR
spring.security.user.password=password
```

EDIT:

```
    @Configuration
public static class ActuatorWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ACTUATOR")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: can u post ur code where you added custom security?

Comment: if ur using basic http auth( which it seems like), try passing in credentials embedded in the url.
So http://actuator:password@host:port/actuator/shutdown

Comment: so http:// followed by actuator:password@host:port/actuator/shutdown.

Comment: @IndraneelBende I have added my code to the OP. I tried the different url, same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to disable csrf in the WebSecurityConfigureAdapter configure method.

```
http.csrf().disable();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. No matter what I did, the actuator/shutdown would return forbidden. The answer above with the `http.csrf().disable();` was the only thing that worked. Please find the reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-csrf

```
package com.broadridge.services.calendar2.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest;

@Configuration
public class ApiSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().
        requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
}

}
```

Comment: Cut and paste, poof! It worked (didn't need the imports). Still probably need some/all of these in `application.properties`: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.expose=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true`